# How to parse log with "dynamically" double quotes

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logparser

I have a similar to following logs

```
4294967295,"adult,low-risk",6564ec78-4995-45b7-b73d-44ee50851dcb,"everything,lost,bla",0
```

The value inside double quotes should be on the same field so i would get something like

```
field1 => 4294967295
field2 => "adult,low-risk"
field3 => 36564ec78-4995-45b7-b73d-44ee50851dcb
field4 => "everything,lost,bla"
field5 => 0
```

But, if the value empty or has a single value the double quotes would not present like:

```
4294967295,,6564ec78-4995-45b7-b73d-44ee50851dcb,everything,0
```

Then if i place my dissect/grok like:

```
%{field1},%{field2},%{field3},%{field4},%{field5}
```

it would return:

```
field1 => 4294967295
field2 => "adult
field3 => low-risk"
field4 => 36564ec78-4995-45b7-b73d-44ee50851dcb
field5 => "everything,lost,bla",0
```

and if i place my dissect/grok like:

```
%{field1},"%{field2}",%{field3},"%{field4}",%{field5}
```

it would work but once the value empty or has a single value like i mentioned above it would return **_grokparsefailure** or **__dissectfailure**

How do i solve this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Try this out

`%{NUMBER:field1},%{DATA:field2},%{UUID:field3},%{DATA:field4},%{NUMBER:field5}`

Comment: This one exactly the same pattern as i used in the first pattern above its just i used dissect and this one using grok. I tried both and it doesn't change anything @Sourav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dissect in preference to grok is often a good idea because it has limited functionality, which means it is cheaper. However, dissect does not know about the quoting conventions for commas in csv files. A csv filter does, so if you use

```
csv { columns => [ "field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5" ] }
```

you will get the result you want.

Comment: It works, i just tried it out using Microsoft Excel CSV data import. I will soon try it using logstash. Thank you very much for your help!